# javascript to make a modal submit a form in rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails form that is a partial to a page and after the user fills out the form they hit a button which brings up a bootstrap modal and the submit for that form is in the footer of the modal. I cant get the form to submit, I believe I need some javascript but I am not too versed in javascript. Here is my partial with the modal, what javascript do I need to make this submit?

```
<%= form_for [:client, Reportapproval.new], :validate => true do |f| %>   <div class="actions">
 <%= f.hidden_field :blah, :value => current_client.name %>   </div>   <div class="block-inline">
  <label>Blah Blah</label><br>
   <%= f.select :client... %>      </div>   <%= f.text_field :client... %>
  <label>
   <%= f.hidden_field :client... %>
  </label>   <div class="text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#client_disclaimer_modal">
    Request a report from this renter
  </button> <!--- This button opens the modal--->   </div>

<!-- Disclaimer Modal -->   <div class="modal fade" id="clent_disclaimer_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Client Disclaimer Agreement</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <strong>NOTICE...<br>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <%= f.submit "Agree & Submit", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>   
  </div> 
 </div>  
 <br />  
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is the error? Modal not popping up or submission error? Also, what's with the ```:client...```?

Comment: The error is the form wont submit when the ````<%= f.submit "Agree & Submit", class: 'btn btn-default' %>```` is clicked within the modal footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for javascript. You have a `form_for`, and a `submit`. Once you click on `submit` it should work.

If it doesn't work, then check the `form_for` parameters like `[:client, Reportapproval.new], :validate => true` if it is correct, and also check if there is something shown in the console, an error or similar once you click on `submit`. It might give you more information where the error is

**Edit:**

Heh, you failed to mention that you are using a gem https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations . It is not a standard rails gem. Check the documentation how to use it and what could be the problem. If you don't want to use it, remove the gem, and remove the `validate => true` and it should be working then

Comment: I will try this, just curious do you know of any other gem that can do validations without reloading the entire page?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery (which you probably are with rails), assign an id to the submit button and an id to your form. After doing this you can write an event handler like so:

```
('#buttonIdyouassigned').click(function(){
     $.post('theroutethatthisformneedstogoto',('#formIdYouAssigned').serialize()) 
})
```

the above code is mostly used if you want to do something like return a json response from the route on the serverside. 
Another option is:

```
('#buttonIdyouassigned').click(function(){
     ('theroutethatthisformneedstogoto').submit();
 })
```

That should submit the form.
More info: [jquery submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)